# Mysql restored itself

Tags: mysql, restore

I have a database in mysql. It is located on my server machine windows server 2008. I am using the system for at least 2 months without any problem. but last night it suddenly restored to an earlier backup I guess. because all my recent data is gone and old datas are in the tables. It really confused me. I dont know if windows restored itself somehow to an earlier date, or mysql restored itself? is there anyway that I can check what happened?

Comment: You can look in the mysql log files.. mayby there is an clue of what happend...

Comment: Have you checked the Windows event log to see whether that provides any clues? Does anybody else access the server, or has it been hacked?