# Mysql restored data itself

Tags: php, mysql, sql

According to this topic [Mysql restored itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797327/mysql-restored-itself).

I have the same problem. I am using the system for about a years and suddenly last night all my data become a data from about 10 days ago. The auto_inclement number has gone back too.

is anyone has clue on this or where can I check what happened on my system?

Database information : 
Database server

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP

Server type: MariaDB

Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Protocol version: 10

Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

phpMyAdmin :

Version information: 4.5.1, latest stable version: 4.7.4

Web server :

Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.35

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 -

PHP extension: mysqli Documentation

PHP version: 5.5.35

Comment: You must have 2 instances of mysql server installed. check swlist. server must been shutdown.. check shutdown logs. when brought up, the webserver started the another mysql.: https://serverfault.com/questions/119614/what-possible-events-could-cause-a-mysql-database-to-revert-to-a-previous-state

Comment: There should be some error logs in /var/logs/. Also, does not this belong to one of the other stack exchange sites?

Comment: @David Hope my server is run on window (localhost). The shutdown logs is the window log or database log? thank you

Comment: The shut down log must be the server log. in your case the windows log.